# How to use Puppeteer and Headless Chrome with Cucumber-js

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cucumberjs, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I am trying to do BDD with cucumber-js and drive the browser testing with Headless Chrome and puppeteer.

Using the documentation from [cucumber node example](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/2.x/docs/nodejs_example.md) and [headless chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome), I get the following errors, the entire code base is avaliable here: [github repo](https://github.com/iowyncrox/cucumberpuppeteer).

***Errors:***

1. TypeError: this.browser.newPage is not a function
2. TypeError: this.browser.close is not a function

**// features/support/world.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

function CustomWorld() {
  this.browser = puppeteer.launch();  
}

defineSupportCode(function({setWorldConstructor}) {
  setWorldConstructor(CustomWorld)
})
```

**// features/step_definitions/hooks.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(function({After}) {
  After(function() {
    return this.browser.close();
  });
});
```

**// features/step_definitions/browser_steps.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var { defineSupportCode } = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(function ({ Given, When, Then }) {
    Given('I am on the Cucumber.js GitHub repository', function (callback) {
        const page = this.browser.newPage();
        return page.goto('https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/tree/master');
    });

    When('I click on {string}', function (string, callback) {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        callback(null, 'pending');
    });

    Then('I should see {string}', function (string, callback) {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        callback(null, 'pending');
    });
});
```

Comment: check out this framework - https://github.com/igniteram/puppeteer-cucumber-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We created [puppeteer-cucumber-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-cucumber-js) to simplify working with Puppeteer and Cucumber:

1. Run `npm install puppeteer-cucumber-js`
2. Create a `features` folder in the root of your project
3. Add a `feature-name.feature` file with your `Given, When, Then` statements
4. Create a `features/step-definitions` folder
5. Add JavaScript steps to execute for each of your features steps
6. Run tests `node ./node_modules/puppeteer-cucumber-js/index.js --headless`

Source code with a working example on [GitHub](https://github.com/orca-scan/puppeteer-cucumber-js#readme)

Answer (score 2):

puppeteer is completely async, so you have to wait it's initialization before using `this.browser`.

But setWorldConstructor is sync function, so you can't wait there. In my example I used Before hook

My example:
https://gist.github.com/dmitrika/7dee618842c00fbc35418b901735656b

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber has been since updated. This is how I have implemented my async puppeteer setup with cucumber. Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/AgoloMarx/5ae3930c3bc5294be12d4a865248386d)

```
const { BeforeAll, Before, AfterAll, After } = require('cucumber');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

Before(async function() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 50 });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  this.browser = browser;
  this.page = page;
})

After(async function() {
  // Teardown browser
  if (this.browser) {
    await this.browser.close();
  }
  // Cleanup DB
})
```